# Question page refresh shows answers in different order

Tags: support, answers

If answers have equal score they displays in random order every time. Is it OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, answers that have the same score are randomly ordered among themselves each time you load the page - that is by design.

Comment: Its worth noting this is to avoid the [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem.